# awk command to map ASCII char to hex code not working

Tags: awk, xxd

I'm experimenting with awk and I thought it would be a cool idea to write a small program that maps every ASCII char with its hex code. this is what ive done so far:

The string is:

```
abshdfitiggwigiwjirjgiejrigjr
```

im keeping it simple and not including returns or tabs etc

I've dumped it into a file seperated by commas so that I can use awk's -F flag to recognize them as fields:

```
a,b,s,h,d,f,i,t,i,g,g,w,i,g,i,w,j,i,r,j,g,i,e,j,r,i,g,j,r,
```

And I've done the same for hex dump of the same file:

```
61,62,73,68,64,66,69,74,69,67,67,77,69,67,69,77,6a,69,72,6a,67,69,65,6a,72,69,67,6a,72,0a,
```

I figured now since they both have the same NF, it would be easier and so I attempted the following awk command:

```
awk -F ',' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){sum[$i]=$i}} END {for(char in sum) { print char, sum[char]} } ' line.txt linebits.txt
```

where line.txt and linebits.txt correspond to the correct files

the output looks like:

```
62 62
h h
72 72
i i
0a 0a
64 64
73 73
j j
w w
65 65
74 74
66 66
67 67
77 77
68 68
a a
69 69
b b
6a 6a
d d
e e
r r
f f
s s
61 61
g g
t t
```

which makes sense ofcourse because sum[$i]=$i is just doing sum[g]=g for example and I'm printing both which are identical

I know why it's showing this output, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Is it possible to specify which file I want? is it possible to grab the index of stdin? i know that sounds crazy haha

the output I want is:

```
char - hex code
char - hex code
.....
```

Comment: Is `sum[i] = $i` what you want? `i` is the index, `$i` is the value at that index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your goal is to learn (about) awk rather than to simply get the ASCII table, which per other answer is easily available.

You don't need any input file(s) for this; you can directly display all the printable characters with

```
awk 'BEGIN{ for(i=32;i<127;i++) printf("%02x %c\n",i,i) }'
```

(This generates one long column, as your attempt did; if you want multicolumns that's left as an exercise.)

OTOH if you want to combine pairs of fields from two lines -- which can be any values not just a char and its hex:

```
awk [-Fasneeded] 'NR==1 { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) save[i]=$i; next }
  { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print save[i],$i }' file ...
# linebreak for ease of reading, may be omitted in use
```

This works whether the two lines come from two files, as in your case, or one file. If you have more than two lines, this pairs fields from line 1 to each subsequent line, a pattern that often makes sense for CSV-type files which have a header on line 1 with names for each column, followed by a variable number of lines with data in each column.

This also preserves the order including any dupes. To eliminate dupes but otherwise keep order:

```
awk [-Fasneeded] 'NR==1 { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) save[i]=$i; next } 
  { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(!dupe[$i]++) print save[i],$i ;delete dupe }' file ...
# the delete dupe can be omitted in the two-line case
```

If you actually want the random order created by `for in` that's also possible, but it makes no sense to me. Some *useful* order such as numerical order or alphabetical order (with dupes eliminated) might make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You've already been given simpler approaches, but since the objective here seems to be to learn awk, here's how I would do it using the approach you described. First, I would not use `,` to separate, it is easier to work with lines for something like that. We can then use the `NR` and `FNR` special variables to connect the two files. `NR` holds the current input line number while `FNR` the input line number *of the file currently being read*. So if we give `awk` two files, with 2 lines each, then `NR` will go from `1` to `4`, but `FNR` will go from `1` to `2` then back to `1` when reading the first line of the second file and then `2`.

Putting that together, we can do:

```bash
## get the characters, one per line
printf '%s\n' {a..z} > chars

## get the 2byte codes as you had in the question. I am sure
## there is a simpler way, but this is the best I could come up with
hexdump -x chars | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sed -n 's/^0a//p' > codes
```

Armed with those files, we can do:

```bash
## Use awk to print them in pairs
$ awk '{ if(NR==FNR){chars[FNR]=$1} else{ print chars[FNR],$1}}' chars codes
a 61
b 62
c 63
d 64
e 65
f 66
g 67
h 68
i 69
j 6a
k 6b
l 6c
m 6d
n 6e
o 6f
p 70
q 71
r 72
s 73
t 74
u 75
v 76
w 77
x 78
y 79
z 7a
```

Of course, this could just as well be done using `paste`, but never mind:

```bash
$ paste chars codes
a   61
b   62
c   63
d   64
e   65
f   66
g   67
h   68
i   69
j   6a
k   6b
l   6c
m   6d
n   6e
o   6f
p   70
q   71
r   72
s   73
t   74
u   75
v   76
w   77
x   78
y   79
z   7a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the GNU `awk`, then you can include the extended library `ordchr`:

```bash
echo abshdfitiggwigiwjirjgiejrigjr |
    awk -lordchr -F '' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%c %x\n", $i, ord($i)}'
a 61
b 62
s 73
h 68
...
```

`ord()` - *function, convert char to decimal*
`printf "%x", ord($i)` - *convert decimal to hex*
Additionally: `chr()` - *convert decimal to char*

Answer (score 0):

Why not, rather than writing your own program, use an existing one? I suggest [`ascii`](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/ascii) from Eric S. Raymond.

To output the hexadecimal values of ASCII characters with the command above, execute the following: `ascii -x`.

**Example output**:

```
   00 NUL    10 DLE    20      30 0    40 @    50 P    60 `    70 p 
   01 SOH    11 DC1    21 !    31 1    41 A    51 Q    61 a    71 q 
   02 STX    12 DC2    22 "    32 2    42 B    52 R    62 b    72 r 
   03 ETX    13 DC3    23 #    33 3    43 C    53 S    63 c    73 s 
   04 EOT    14 DC4    24 $    34 4    44 D    54 T    64 d    74 t 
   05 ENQ    15 NAK    25 %    35 5    45 E    55 U    65 e    75 u 
   06 ACK    16 SYN    26 &    36 6    46 F    56 V    66 f    76 v 
   07 BEL    17 ETB    27 '    37 7    47 G    57 W    67 g    77 w 
   08 BS     18 CAN    28 (    38 8    48 H    58 X    68 h    78 x 
   09 HT     19 EM     29 )    39 9    49 I    59 Y    69 i    79 y 
   0A LF     1A SUB    2A *    3A :    4A J    5A Z    6A j    7A z 
   0B VT     1B ESC    2B +    3B ;    4B K    5B [    6B k    7B { 
   0C FF     1C FS     2C ,    3C <    4C L    5C \    6C l    7C | 
   0D CR     1D GS     2D -    3D =    4D M    5D ]    6D m    7D } 
   0E SO     1E RS     2E .    3E >    4E N    5E ^    6E n    7E ~ 
   0F SI     1F US     2F /    3F ?    4F O    5F _    6F o    7F DEL
```

Comment: Or on nearly all Unix systems just `man ascii`

Comment: "I'm experimenting with awk" -- he's using the ASCII table as an awk exersize, it's not the actual goal.